# It should be "Many people took a rest"or"Many people took rest"?

Tags: word-choice, uncountable-nouns

It should be "Many people took a rest"or"Many people took rest"?
Is it right to say"We don't have good sleep?" I only know i should say"i don't have a good sleep."

Answer (score 0):

**"Rest"** and **"sleep"** work similarly as nouns - both have countable and non-countable forms.

As non-countables they are roughly equivalent.

***Rest* is beneficial, *sleep* is even more beneficial.**

But as countables, whilst you might say **I'm having a *rest***, you wouldn't say **I'm having a *sleep***, for the obvious reason that one doesn't talk when sleeping (not coherently anyway).

But there is nothing whatever wrong with **I've just had a good *sleep***.

Comment: Come at any time. If I'm having a sleep don't be shy to wake me up.

Answer (score 0):

Many rested after blank blank blank.

Less on the nose is to describe how they looked and why they were tired? (in a novel.)

Past tense many people rested  or many (leave out people as its obvious) felt the neef to rest after the blank drained their energy.